# Split function does not work when calling function

Tags: javascript, split

I am using the Split function to take a selected option value and split by each pipe delimeter.

The value of exploded[2] is correctly shown as 10.00 when outputted but the finance function does not return a value and my div does not get updated with fresh text.

If I swap exploded[2] to a literal 10.00 within the function like this:

```
finance(exploded[0], exploded[1], 10.00, exploded[3]);
```

it works.  Similarly, if I make exploded[2] = 10.00 like this:

```
var test = 10.00;
finance(exploded[0], exploded[1], test, exploded[3]);
```

it works too.  Have I done something stupid?

The Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#finance').change(function() {     
    selected_value = $('#finance').val();
    exploded = selected_value.split('|');
    finance(exploded[0], exploded[1], exploded[2], exploded[3]);    
  });

  function finance(code, order_cost, depost_pc, deposit_val) {
    my_fd_obj = new FinanceDetails(code, order_cost, depost_pc, deposit_val);
    $('#finance_per_month').html(my_fd_obj.m_inst);     
  }

  });

</script>
```

The HTML

```
<select name='finance' id='finance'>
  <option value="ONIF10|399.00|10.00|39.90">10 Months 0% Finance</option>
  <option value="ONIF18|399.00|10.00|39.90">18 Months 0% Finance</option>
  <option value="ONIF24|399.00|10.00|39.90">24 Months 0% Finance</option>
  <option value="ISIB36-3.9|399.00|10.00|39.90">36 Months 3.9% Finance</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `split` is working for sure, probably the issue can be found from `FinanceDetails()`. Also it would be easier to pass the whole array instead of a bunch of arguments. Also you say: "`... the finance function does not return a value ...`", Obviously it doesn't , there's no `return something` in the said function, and actually there's no receiver for the return value either in the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to say for sure without knowing more about `FinanceDetails`, but the difference between `exploded[2]` and `10.00` is that the former is a *string* (`"10.00"`, not `10.00`). 99% of the time, code will implicitly coerce strings to numbers, but again not knowing what's in `FinanceDetails`...

`parseFloat(exploded[2])` might solve the problem. Or just `+exploded[2]`.

I'd expect you would need to do this for the other args as well, if they're also meant to be numbers.

Comment: @monkey64: LOL You just did. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sometimes I feel sure you've a chrystal ball ; ).